# Does ssh save the code in the remote computer?

Tags: python, linux, security, ssh, privacy

When running python code using ssh on remote computer by a sudo user, does it save the code in the remote computer ? does the root user can see actual python code?

```
ssh user@remotehost < python /home/codes/script.py
```

Comment: Python won't save it. The ssh server could potentially log it, but that may be a question for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the command "ssh user@remotehost < python /home/codes/script.py" will not save the Python file on the remote server. In fact, this command is not correct and will result in an error.

The < symbol is used to redirect the contents of a file to the standard input of a command. In this case, it is being used to redirect the output of the python command to the standard input of the ssh command, which is not a valid operation.

If you want to run a Python script that is located on your local machine on a remote server using SSH, you can use the cat command to send the contents of the script to the remote server and pipe it into the python command like this:

"cat /path/to/local_script.py | ssh user@remotehost python -"

This will send the contents of the local Python script to the remote server and execute it using the python command. However, it will not save the Python file on the remote server.